# Authenticating AD user automatically and manually - WebAPI 2 server and SPA client

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I'm developing an Enterprise/Internet Application with WebAPI 2 RESTful server and SPA web client (Angular2) —So I have two separated projects created using ASP.NET 4.6 Empty template and both use OWIN and are IIS hosted.

The requirement for Authentication is:

1. Active Directory user which is logged in to the workstation will authenticated automatically once she opens any page from app in the browser if user id/name found in the database, **with no need to enter her user/pass**. Let name this as ***auto-login***. Else if it's not found in the DB it will redirected to the login page.
2. Also there should be a logout option which redirects user to the login page after logging she out.
3. In the login page any AD user can enter her/his AD user&pass and after  successful check against database (existed) and AD (valid credential) she/he will logged in to the system (Obviously it may be different than user currently is logged in to the workstation)
4. In addition to the web client it will have other clients such mobile apps which will connect and be served by the WebAPI back-end. Users will login there using their AD user & pass too. Let name it ***manual-login.***

According to the REST architecture and having both AD enterprise and internet/mobile users together, the authentication should be token based —this is what I found till now but I'm not sure.

I read about OWIN Authentication architecture and Windows Authentication and I checked [MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth), Now I think it is the nearest solution for this requirement as it lets app-defined users to authenticate side by side of windows/AD users. But even after dig into it and its [SPA sample](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth/blob/master/src/SPA/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L73) I didn't found my way yet and confused.

Anyone can help?

5. What should I actually do on the WebApi server and SPA Client to accomplish those authentication requirements?
6. Which middlewares should I add and how should config/manipulate them?

   `UseCookieAuthentication` ?

   `UseExternalSignInCookie` ?

   `UseOAuthBearerTokens` ?
7. Can I rely just on Bearer tokens (using OAuthBearerTokens MW) and get same token for authenticated windows users to unify authentication model based on bearer tokens? If so, how?
8. How and where should I put my code for checking that AD user exists in the DB and if not so reject the authentication?

Thanks a lot.